# Django group by hour

Tags: python, django, orm, group-by

I have the following model in Django.

```
class StoreVideoEventSummary(models.Model):
    Customer = models.ForeignKey(GlobalCustomerDirectory, null=True, db_column='CustomerID', blank=True, db_index=True)
    Store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True, db_column='StoreID', blank=True, related_name="VideoEventSummary")
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    PeopleCount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to find out the number of people entering the store each hour.

To achieve this, I'm trying to group the rows by the hour on `Timestamp` and sum the `PeopleCount` column.

```
store_count_events = StoreVideoEventSummary.objects.filter(Timestamp__range=(start_time, end_time),
                                                       Customer__id=customer_id,
                                                       Store__StoreName=store)\
        .order_by("Timestamp")\
        .extra({
            "hour": "date_part(\'hour\', \"Timestamp\")"
        }).annotate(TotalPeople=Sum("PeopleCount"))
```

This doesn't seem to group the results by the hour, it merely adds a new column `TotalPeople` which has the same value as `PeopleCount` to each row in the query set.

Comment: I'm missing something..where is the "StartTime" coming from? `"hour": "date_part(\'hour\', \"StartTime\")"`

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just break it into two steps

```python
import itertools
from datetime import datetime


# ...

def date_hour(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%x %H")


objs = StoreVideoEventSummary.objects.filter(
    Timestamp__range=(start_time, end_time),
    Customer__id=customer_id,
    Store__StoreName=store
).order_by("Timestamp")

groups = itertools.groupby(objs, lambda x: date_hour(x.Timestamp))

# since groups is an iterator and not a list you have not yet traversed the list
for group, matches in groups:  # now you are traversing the list ...
    print(group, "TTL:", sum(1 for _ in matches))
```

This allows you to group by several distinct criteria

Of you just want the hour regardless of date just change `date_hour`

```python
def date_hour(timestamp):
   return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%H")
```

If you wanted to group by day of the week you just use

```python
def date_day_of_week(timestamp):
   return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%w %H")
```

And update `itertools.groupby`'s lambda to use `date_day_of_week`.

Comment: Totally forgot about `itertools`. Doing the grouping in Python works and if all else fails I think this is the method I'm going for. Would be nice to do it in the database if possible as I would imagine that is much faster. Then again my datasets aren't that large (famous last words!).

Comment: you would be suprised ... it probably would not be faster in the database :P

Comment: This approach seems to work fine. We haven't encountered any problems, likely because our dataset is small.

Comment: since your really only iterating it once it should be O(N) ... which should be pretty manageable

Comment: @JoranBeasley +1 for the most elegant solution. It worked for me but I wonder what does `sum(1 for _ in matches)` syntax refer to? I would like to research this, but have no idea what to google for.

Answer (score 1):

Building off your original code, could you try:

```
store_count_events = StoreVideoEventSummary.objects.filter(Timestamp__range=(start_time, end_time), Customer__id=customer_id, Store__StoreName=store)\
    .extra({
        "hour": "date_part(\'hour\', \"Timestamp\")"
    })\
    .values("hour")\
    .group_by("hour")\
    .annotate(TotalPeople=Sum("PeopleCount"))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It's similar to the previous, the only difference seems to be I only get 2 fields `hour` and `TotalPeople` per row now instead of an entire row.

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late here, but taking cues from the doc, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

the below filter should work for you.

```
store_count_events = StoreVideoEventSummary.objects.filter(
    Timestamp__range=(start_time, end_time),
    Customer__id=customer_id,
    Store__StoreName=store
).order_by(
    'Timestamp'
).extra(
    select={
        'hour': 'hour(Timestamp)'
    }
).values(
    'hour'
).annotate(
    TotalPeople=Sum('PeopleCount')
)
```

Comment: What is start_time and end_time and where are they defined ?

Comment: what is hour doing in hour(TimeStamp)?