# How to group objects by hour with django querysets?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # ...
```

How do I, in a view,

- Get All actions objects

  - `Action.objects`
- Group them into 24 brackets (using QuerySet properties, probably a `group` ?), like so:

  ```
  { 0: [Action1, Action2, Action3], # timestamp between 00:00 and 00:59, any day
    1: [Action4], # timestamp between 01:00 and 01:59, any day
    # ...
    23: [ActionN] # timestamp between 23:00 and 23:59, any day
  }
  ```

Basically, I want to have a graph showing how many Actions were done , with a resolution of an hour.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465013/django-group-by-hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the [ExtractHour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) function to get hour from your datetime field, and then group your records into a `dict`.

Sample code for your reference:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour

# create a new field to extract hour from timestamp field
actions = Action.objects.annotate(hour=ExtractHour('created'))

# create a default dict to insert a list if key is not exist
results = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for row in actions:
    results[row.hour].append(row)
```

**NOTE:**

If you are using mysql database, pls remember to load timezone info before using `Extract` functions

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```