# group rest api data by day and hour. Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm super new to django and the rest API framework. I have a project that I am working on using both and vueJS for the front end. I need to serialize some data for a chart.

For one of the API end points I am trying to group the data like so:

```
    "day_of_the_week": {
        "9am":[{"job":".."}],
        "10am":[{"job":"..."}],
        "11am": [{"job": ".."}],
        ...
    }
```

I am using a Job class, for reference this is how the jobs end point looks like: [jobs-api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqs01.png)

So instead of what i have on the picture I am creating a new endpoint where i will only show one object that contains the data for any given day. On the front end there is a chart with filters that let the user filter the jobs by the day they request. On load, when the user has given no day of the week, the end point will return the object of 'today'.

Because I am new to this, I have no idea where to do this, my initial thought was to filter on the views.py, but for now I have done it in the serializer which gives me the error "Object of type Job is not JSON serializable".

This is how the serializer looks like:
[jobs-by-day-serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsqV8.png)

Clearly, there is something that I am not quite grasping, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
this is my views.py now, I have added the filter for the queryset to filter by day, so I can filter by day now:
[jobs_by_day_viewset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZN8b.png)

Comment: Filtering should be done in views.py. How does your views.py look?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I added the viewset to the question

Comment: You need to do two things: 1) A group by query. May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465013/django-group-by-hour.   2)You need to create your own serializer (that can serialize data as you wish, not a model serializer I guess). You should  pass the result from 1 to that serializer . OR, you may not even need a serializer, if output from 1 directly works for you.

Comment: thank you, i tried this approach, but cant get it to work properly, I am getting the error: unhashable 'slice'. I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that i need to convert the dictionary into a json object somehow?

Comment: Did you get the result from query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers given provides a solution for one part of the question.
I managed to solve the second part. Once I could filter my queryset by day of the week I still had to group every object by the hour in which it had been started.
This is how i solved it:

```
 def get(self, request):
    params = self.get_params()
    queryset = Job.objects.filter(
        dt_start__week_day=params['day'], dt_start__gte=params['dt_start'], dt_end__lte=params['dt_end'])
    queryset_started = queryset.annotate(hour=ExtractHour('dt_start'))
    queryset_ended = queryset.annotate(hour=ExtractHour('dt_end'))
    started = []
    ended = []
    total_jobs =[]
    for n in range(0, 23):
        queryset_end = queryset_ended.filter(hour=n)
        ended.append(round(queryset_end.count() / queryset.count() * 100, 2))
        queryset3 = queryset_started.filter(hour=n)
        started.append(round(queryset3.count() / queryset.count() * 100, 2))
    for x in range(len(started)):
        total_jobs.append(round(started[x]+ended[x], 2))
```

I used a viewset that extended from APIview instead of the modelviewsets so that i was able to return an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct way of doing it would be to implement the model serializer and then define the views.

A good reason for implementing different serializers is to return different result for the same model. But in your case you just need an specific subset of `Job` so I think the view is a better choice.

I assume you already implement `JobSerializer`, and probably you have a `JobViewSet` to L/C/U/M over the model.

So, now you just need to implement a new view for these task. Something like this could work,

```py
from jobs.models import Job
from jobs.serializers import JobSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class JobByDayList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = JobSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get the day from parameters
        day_query = self.kwargs['day_query']
        # here your logic to get desire queryset
        return queryset
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have added the viewset in the question, i have the filter for fay that should be working, but i dont know how to separate the jobs in an array per hour..