# Django - Group by, split by date range

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    store_id = models.TextField()
    day_dt = models.DateField()
    param1 = models.IntegerField()
    param2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Some data example:

```
store_id | day_dt     | param1 | param2
----------------------------------------
STORE1   | 2021-09-30 | 10     | 30
STORE2   | 2021-09-31 | 20     | 40
....
STORE1   | 2021-10-01 | 4      | 5
STORE1   | 2021-10-02 | 6      | 10
STORE1   | 2021-10-03 | 2      | 5
STORE2   | 2021-10-02 | 3      | 7
STORE2   | 2021-10-03 | 1      | 19
....
```

I need to split data into groups by `store_id` and interval (`day_dt` shoould be between `2021-10-01` and `2021-10-04`):

```
STORE1   | 2021-10-01
STORE1   | 2021-10-02
STORE1   | 2021-10-03
```

and

```
STORE2   | 2021-10-02
STORE2   | 2021-10-03
```

and then apply to each (of two) groups aggregation: Avg('param1') and Avg('param2').

The expected output for data example:

```
store_id | param1_avg | param2_avg
----------------------------------
STORE1   | 6          | 10
STORE2   | 2          | 13
```

How could I do this aggregation with ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

MyModel.objects.filter(
    date_dt__range=('2021-10-01', '2021-10-04')
).values('store_id').annotate(
    param1_avg=Avg('param1'),
    param2_avg=Avg('param2')
).order_by('store_id')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of dictionaries that will look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'store_id': 'STORE1', param1_avg: 6, param2_avg: 10},
    {'store_id': 'STORE2', param1_avg: 2, param2_avg: 13}
]>
```

stores that have no `MyModel` records for the given date range will *not* have a dictionary object in the resulting queryset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465013/django-group-by-hour) that is the simplest way.

But the Django solution is using Expression and [writing your own Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#writing-your-own-query-expressions). In this solution, you make an expression like `Hours` and use it in the `annotate` function like: `.annotate(Hours("day_dt"))`. You should override the `as_sql` function to write your custom SQL method or override the `as_sqlite` and `as_postgresql` functions for different support DBMS.