# Django models: Query to Get the data from the table an hourly basis

Tags: python, django, database

I am working in Django and python.
I have the data for minutes basis in my database please have a look at the image, But when am querying it I want to have a query which fetches the data on an hourly basis.

Table Name: `TrafficTrend_SDP_BHCA`

[image]

This image has the table name and the columns it has.
I have the full length of data from date `202109270835` to date `202109290956`

`202109270835` is the date hour format. `20210927` is the date, `08` is an hour and `35` is minutes.

From this table I want to fetch data on an hourly basis.

**Example**: data started with `202109270835`, so I want to get the data something like for `08` hours and `09` hours (an hourly basis).
and for each hour the respective columns `VCS1FI` and `VCS1FI_Fail` values should be summed up individually.

**Output** could be for `2021092708` hours `VCS1FI=""`, `VCS1FI_Fail=""` and for `2021092709` hours `VCS1FI= ""`, `VCS1FI_Fail=""`.

{
"Date":"202111200800",
"Vcs1FI":101,
"Vcs1II":101,
"Node_Name_id":"s1"
}
{
"Date":"202111200801",
"Vcs1FI":120,
"Vcs1II":120,
"Node_Name_id":"s1"
}
.....etc till 202111200859
{
"Date":"202111200900",
"Vcs1FI":101,
"Vcs1II":101,
"Node_Name_id":"s1"
}
{
"Date":"202111200901",
"Vcs1FI":120,
"Vcs1II":120,
"Node_Name_id":"s1"
}
.....etc till 202111200959

All the keys above are column names.
this is what we have(got the data in json format). now for 2021112008 hour i want to have the data like 2021112008:("VFI"+"VII"), 2021112009("VFI"+"VII")

Comment: Is the hour to fetch is fixed? Or is it given by user or known one?

Comment: hour should be whatever is coming from the table , lets say from table up i am getting 202109270835, so 08 is hour , 35 is minutes so here based on 08 since it is hour, i should be getting the data for that 08th hr, 09th hr, 10 th hr, even though it has for minutes like 0835, 0836 and os on, all these minutes for 08 combinely should give the result for 08 hr etc

Comment: Hour is not fixed it will come as different on timely basis

Comment: I think you can use slicing to find the hour, like let's say timestamp='202109270835', you can get the hour as timestamp[4:6].
So in the list of data you can check like this

Comment: But i will some huge number of data , i cannnot go thoguht each and every data for this.  in mysql i found this , may be if you get some idea how we can do it in django please let me know   https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-get-data-for-every-hour-in-mysql/

Comment: Please refer to the below post, which would help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465013/django-group-by-hour